# Reasking a question about automated assessment tools

Tags: discussion

Recently, [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20226/13852) on recommendations for automated assessment tools for programming assignments was migrated to this site and quickly closed (rightfully so, as it was a simple shopping list question). Since this is a topic I'm currently interested it and the original poster apparently did not follow the migration, I'm considering reasking it myself in a (hopefully) more suitable way. However, my main interest is in programming assignments posed as part of courses in applied mathematics, so I'm a bit torn about whether https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ might not be a more suitable forum for it.

So I'd like to gauge the interest in the general topic for this community first. Do you think a generic question would be useful? If so, what would make for good bits of information to ask for? (I was planning on asking for -- positive or negative -- experiences in practice, but I'm worried that this would be too opinion-based.)

Comment: Actually, the linked question has **not** yet been closed—votes to close have been cast to close, but not enough to place it on hold. That said, it _is_ a shopping question, and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about:

- The pros and cons of using such systems
- The features needed to use such systems properly
- Handling the results of such systems (for instance: "What happens if a system breaks down?" "What happens if a student complains about having to use such a system?")

would be on-topic in my opinion.

Questions that would be off-topic would include:

- Recommendations for which specific system to buy
- Questions that ask about how to use a particular system

Comment: I was certainly going for the former. I've gone ahead and asked the question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20578/13852, if it's too specific to mathematics, feel free to migrate to MathEducators (if they want it).